# Blur then focus Effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiblureffect

I am making a single view application in Xcode and I am having a little trouble*(By little I mean **BIG** trouble!)

I wanted to make a clone of the Apple's News app home page where the buttons are are blurry than come to focus.I want to use that effect for three different ui elements.**I have been trying for days but no success. :(**

Is there a way of doing the blur than focus animation to a label a button And image view? If so can you please guide me on how to do it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: animate the `opacity` of the visual effect's view; that does the job for you.

Comment: Sorry but i want it to start blurry then to focus.Thank you!

Comment: Make a try, if you create a blurred element, slightly bigger in front of it and then, opacity around 50%, and animate to 0, I think it may cause the effect you expect.

Comment: Thanks i am working on it now! :)

Comment: @HamzaW, well... then you need to do the animation from `1.0` to `0.0`...

Comment: please like my question